# How to get last Key or Value in Kotlin Map collection

Tags: kotlin, dictionary, associative-array

How can I get the last key or value in a `Kotlin Map` collection? It seems like it cannot be done by using an index value.

Comment: What do you want 'last' to mean? Some map implementations [do not have an order](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-hash-map/), but [some maps preserve insertion order](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-linked-hash-map/).

Comment: Please be aware maps are data structures that are generally unordered. They don't have the concept of the last element. Some implementations keep items in the insertion order and the default implementation in Kotlin does this. So if you know the map was created with e.g. `mapOf()` then you can use `entries.last()`, but otherwise it may return pretty much a random item.

Comment: @aSemy By 'last', I mean the last key, value pair in the `Map` collection (i.e. if looping through the collection with `foreach` the pair I'm looking for is the last pair the method iterates to.)

Comment: @broot I think I understand what you're saying. If I do `.entries.last()` on a `Map` collection for which I do not already know its insertion order, then the returned `key, value` pair can be anything. But this is fine for my use case. I ended up using `.entries.last()`. Thanks.

Comment: This is not exactly what I meant. Various implementations of maps could use different ordering of items. `TreeMap` uses custom ordering specified by the user, `LinkedHashMap` uses insertion order, `HashMap` is entirely random. Even if you know the insertion order of items, but you don't know what's the implementation of the map, the last item is still not very meaningful to you. Kotlin code most of the time uses `LinkedHashMap` (insertion order), Java code most of the time uses `HashMap` (random order).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a couple ways it can be done. While you can't elegantly print a map directly, you may print it's entry set.

The first way, and the way that I **DO NOT** recommend, is by calling the `.last()` function on the entry set. This can be accomplished with `testMap.entries.last()`. The reason I don't recommend this method is because in real data this method is non-deterministic -- meaning there's no way to guarantee the characteristics of the value returned.

While I don't recommend this method, I don't know your application and this may be sufficient.

I **DO** recommend using the `.sortedBy()` function on your entry set, and then calling `.last()` on it. This allows you to make some sort of assumption about the results returned, something that is typically necessary, otherwise why do you want the last?

See this example comparing the two methods and then comparing the method against the order you would get if you iterate with the `.forEach` function:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val testMap = mutableMapOf<Long, String>()

    testMap[1] = "Hello"
    testMap[5] = "World"
    testMap[3] = "Foobar"

    println(testMap.entries.last())
    println(testMap.entries.sortedBy { it.key }.last())

    println("\norder via loop:")

    testMap
        .entries
        .forEach {
            println("\t$it")
        }
}
```

Take a look at the output:

```
3=Foobar
5=World

order via loop:
1=Hello
5=World
3=Foobar
```

Here we see that the value returned from `.last()`, is the last value that was inserted into the map - the same happens with `.forEach`. This is okay, but usually we want our map to have some sort of order. In this example, i've called for the entry set to be sorted by the key value, so that our call to `.last()` on the entry set returns the key/value pair with the largest key.

Comment: It's actually already sorted by `key` value. I have a specific use case in my Android app where I'm displaying a list of shopping list items sorted by category in a `LazyList` composable. So the `key` is the category and the `value` is the shopping list items `List` that I iterate through a `foreach` method. I have a divider at the bottom of each item but I don't want to include it for the last item in the last category listing. This is why I want to get the last `key, value` pair to check against the current `key,value` pair.

Comment: @RajNarayanan then the first solution should be work fine for your use case if you know it's already sorted (`testMap.entries.last()`)